# Force PDF to display inline, even when Content-Disposition says otherwise?

Tags: pdf, iframe, browser, embed, content-disposition

I am embedding PDF in an IFRAME from a server that is unfortunately serving them as `Content-Disposition:attachment;`.

Is there *any* way to force the browser to display the PDF inline? Unfortunately I cannot change the headers for the PDF file linked in the iframe.

Comment: Can you download it in your own server-side code and then point the client's IFRAME SRC to your own page?

Comment: I could though that's less than ideal. Might be the only solution though.

Comment: find any solution to this? .. having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You could use pdf.js library for rendering pdf in html page.
[Mozilla Pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

> **HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PDF.js Learning</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="pdf.js"></script>
  <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>

 </body>
</html>
```

> **JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
 var url = "www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";

 PDFJS.getDocument(url)
  .then(function(pdf) {
   return pdf.getPage(1);
   })
 .then(function(page) {

 var scale = 1.5;


 var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

 // Get canvas#the-canvas

 var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');

 // Fetch canvas' 2d context

 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 // Set dimensions to Canvas

 canvas.height = viewport.height;
 canvas.width = viewport.width;

 // Prepare object needed by render method

  var renderContext = {
 canvasContext: context,
 viewport: viewport
 };

 // Render PDF page

  page.render(renderContext);
 });
```

Comment: Does this work though? Since we have a downloadable attachment and not a pdf in the first place